# Suppose that $|G| = p^aq$, where p and q are primes and a > 0, Then $G$ is not simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Proof :

We can assume that  p$ \neq $ q and $n_p >1 $, so $n_p$ = q. Now choose distinct Sylow p- subgroups $S$ and $T$ of $G$ such that $|S\cap T|$ is as larger as possibe and write $D = S \cap T$.

if $D$ = 1 , then every pair od distinct Sylow p - subgroups of $G$ intersect trrivally, So the total number of elements whose order is of the form $p^b$ is $q(p^a -1)$ and the number of element is atmost $|G| -q(p^a - 1) = q$ elements with order not divisble by p. itfollows that if $Q \in Syl_q(G)$, then $Q$ is exactle the set of these elements and $Q$ is unique and $Q$ is normal in $G$, $G$ is not simple, as required.

> > I want to help to prove that if $|D|$ >1

Comment: See Theorem 1.36 in Isaacs' book "Finite Group Theory".

Comment: I think that you can use the technique described in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59497/11619) to reach your goal.

Comment: Here is a quick summary of that argument. let $P$ be an intersection  $S \cap T$ of two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups $S$ and $T$ of maximal size. Then $P$ is strictly contained in $N_S(P)$ and in $N_T(P)$ so $N_G(P)$ has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup and hence it has $q$, the same number as $G$. So $P$ is contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, and hence it is their intersection, so $P \lhd G$.